# Continuous random variable question

Tags: statistics

$ X $ is a non-negative continuous random variable with density function $f$ and distribution function $F$.

Use integration by parts to show that

$ \int_0^{\infty}  ( 1- F(x)) dx = 
\int_0^{\infty}xf(x)dx  $

I'm quite puzzled on how to even integrate $F(X)$ to get $f(x)$  :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** In the usual calculus notation for integration by parts, let $u=1-F(x)$ and $dv=dx$. Then $du=-f(x)\,dx$ and we can take $v=x$.

**Added:** As pointed out by  беркай. the fact that $\lim_{x\to\infty}x(1-F(x))=0$ requires justification. This takes a few lines. For details, please see [this part](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function#Complementary_cumulative_distribution_function_.28tail_distribution.29) of the Wikipedia article on cumulative distribution functions.

Comment: How does it follow that $x(1-F(x))=0$ as $x \to \infty$? It's not so clear to me. L'Hospital rule may help but it also needs some justifications. What's your argument?